# Problemas al redireccionar un parámetro Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Mi intención es hacer el envío de un dato usando el redirect de RoR de esta manera

```
redirect_to :controller => :GenerarPago, :action => :reference_number, :clave => mi_clave
```

Pero en el controlador **GenerarPago** Donde tengo **reference_number** como una función me manda el siguiente error

> wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)

mandando el error en **GenerarPago#reference_number**

Si alguien me pudiera orientar que sucede

La definición de la función es:

```
def reference_number(clave)
```

Comment: Para la próxima, toma la iniciativa y agrega de antemano el error completo y el código involucrado, no esperes a que te lo pidan . Por lo que veo, al redireccionar está tratando de llamar a  `reference_number`, pero tienes definida la función para que reciba un parámetro, lo cual no corresponde para actions. Ese `reference_number` ¿lo tienes definido en tu `routes.rb` o es solo un método auxiliar de tu controlador?

Comment: No esta definido en el routes.rb  de hecho casi nada esta en el archivo y me hizo falta aclarar que la versión que uso de ruby es 1.8.7 y la función si recibe un parámetro agrego la definición a la pregunta original

Comment: Creo que no me expliqué correctamente, por lo que das a entender `reference_number` no es un action, es solo un método, no lo puedo confirmar al 100% porque aun no pones el código que deberías haber puesto, pero con decirme que no está en tu `routes.rb` me es suficiente para suponer eso. No se si esto es un código que hizo alguien más o tu lo hiciste, pero los actions no reciben parámetros y si vas a usar un `redirect_to`, lo que le pases como parámetro en `:action => ` debe estar definido en tu archivos de `routes.rb`, aparte de ser un método que no reciba parámetros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estas tratando de enviar un dato como si fuera PHP o algún otro lenguaje donde se asignan entre paréntesis los parámetros que esta va a recibir en el caso de tu función (que por cierto ignoro si lo estas haciendo así) debes incluir el hash params para que tengas acceso al dato que enviás

```
params[:symbol]
```

y deberás de pasar de

```
reference_number(clave)
```

a

```
referece_number
claveGuardada=params[:clave]
```

En el caso del redirect_to no es necesario cambiar nada pero siempre que quieras recuperar un parámetro va con params[:symbol]